# Cant get html video play on IOS

Tags: html, video, cpanel

My website's videos won't play on ios devices. They'll play on desktop and in the mobile viewer but not on actual iphone no matter the browser. It doesn't matter what video or format, I've tried several formats and videos, if it's a video uploaded to server it won't show in iOS. The only vids I've gotten to show up are ones sourced from URLs.

```
  <video playsinline controls>
<source src="novaHowl2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="novaHowl2.ogg" type="video/ogg"></video>
```

I've made my entire website https://www.huskybiz.com just a video of my dog which you would see just fine unless you're looking on iphone.

Comment: tried above url in chrome and i can play the video. Though it loads in pause state which is expected as mobile browser do not play a video on load unless played in mute state

Comment: @Sandeep Really...on a mobile device?

Comment: @Sandeep Ohh thanks for the knowledge. Maybs it's just an iphone or just my phone thing.

Comment: `The owner of this website (www.huskybiz.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (53255a043aa46fa6-ua60).`
This is the error on safari. maybe something to do with user agent

Comment: @Sandeep or something with cloudflare. It works on safari on desktop for me and doesnt work on safari or any other browser on my phone so idk.

Comment: oh yes. And it does not work for me on desktop safari. I get an error Access denied | www.huskybiz.com used cloudflare to restrict access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202035/discussion-between-sandeep-and-harper-creek).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

Use absolute URLs in 'Video src' attribute(to do this you can upload the video in pvt youtube channel and just post the link there)

Some devices may take little extra time to load the video

Change the mobile device and try

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the source tag, as per the documentation about the html 5 audio and video tag on [Apple Developers site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html), you just have to use the video tag and add your source file to src. in your case, it would be like:

```html
<video src="novaHowl2.mp4" controls></video>
<video src="novaHowl2.ogg" controls></video>
```

For more information you can checkout the documentation on https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html